# What files do I need to push when adding a swift playground to a public GitHub repo

Tags: swift, github, swift-playground

I'm adding some swift playgrounds to a public GitHub repo but i'm unsure which files to commit and push.

Here are the files in one playground

```
File.playground/Contents.swift
File.playground/contents.xcplayground
File.playground/playground.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
File.playground/playground.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
File.playground/xcuserdata/username.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
```

Note: I replaced the playground name with `File` and my username with `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not yet added those files to the index (if you have, but not committed, you can do a `git reset`, to unstage them), you can add a `.gitignore` with, as its content, the one form [`github/gitignore` `Swift.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore).

Then do a `git status`: you can add, commit and push the files which are still listed.